# DIV Horizontal scroll, how to onload to ID

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, containers, onload

Have a site with MANY horizontally scrolling DIV containers. On one of the containers we want it to scroll to a certain position onLoad. Recommendations to what the best solution is?

To complicate it a little more, the container is vertically far down (i.e. below the fold) on the page and would rather not have the onLoad result in having the page scroll vertically down to this container, merely have this specific container scrolled horizontally and nothing else. Is this also possible?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [scrollLeft](http://help.dottoro.com/ljcjgrml.php) property for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/v6EwS/

```
document.getElementById('foo').scrollLeft = 500;​
```

Comment: Thanks, that does it. A follow-up, is an integer solution the only way to go? Or is there a DIV ID solution. I don't mind doing the math of the DIV widths to adjust, just wondering.

Comment: Yeah, it only takes an integer. If there is an element in there you want to slide to then you will have to calculate the left hand offset from the container.