# How scroll a horizontal grid to a specific place on page Load - responsive solution needed

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

A similar question was asked 8 years ago here:
[DIV Horizontal scroll, how to onload to ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915195/div-horizontal-scroll-how-to-onload-to-id)

and the answer was:

```
document.getElementById('foo').scrollLeft = 500;​
```

But I have a Bootstrap 4 site that's responsive - so I don't know how wide each card is (in the scrolling div) as it will vary with the device.

Is there now a way that I can move/scroll it to the 'n'th div. on page load?

[image]

PS - And like the earlier OP the scrolling div is halfway down the page - so a simple Anchor link isn't appropriate ;(

Answer (score 0):

You must first consider the width of the div that is dynamic as a variable and this variable specifies the scroll rate.

```
 var size=$("div").width()
 document.getElementById('foo').scrollLeft = size;​
```

Comment: Thanks @maryam I will first do some tests to see if all the divs are the same width  (they are all set to w-100)

Comment: Whoops - It is col-auto they are set to not w-100, but they are still slighly different widths!  I may need to fix this first for an easy javascript solution.